# Strange Error Using putExtra

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to import a string from an intention and put that string into another intention. Now I am seeing a strange error on the putExtra method. When I place my mouse cursor over the line's error mark on the left side it says:

" Multiple Markers at this line: 
-Syntax error on '(' token, delete this token
-Syntax error on ')' token, delete this token "

Obviously I need the parenthesis so deleting them will not solve the problem. Has anyone ever encountered this before?

```
public class CountDown extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
private Handler handler = new Handler();

//import the intention from Starting Point Activity
Intent intention1=getIntent();
final String message = intention1.getStringExtra(StartingPoint.EXTRA_MESSAGE);



//Create the intention that is supposed to go to the Display Message Activity
Intent broadcastSM = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity1.class);
broadcastSM.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
```

Comment: you want to see messages from logcat?

Comment: Yes,In debugging android app, logcat is the most reliable source

Comment: Just by quick look at the code, it seems that you are not doing `intention1.getStringExtra(StartingPoint.EXTRA_MESSAGE);` and other things inside the `onCreate()`. If not, then you should call these inside the onCreate function.

Comment: From your description, this sounds like a compiler error, not a runtime error. Actually, it sounds like your IDE is indicating an error. So, please let us know: 1. Which line of code is indicated as having the error (remember that we can't see line numbers). 2. Do you actually get a compiler error too, or is it just the IDE telling you this?  3. Which IDE are you using?